Extracting contents from MS Office files and convert to HTML using NodeJS?
I am making an Electronic Document Management System (EDMS) with NodeJS and a web frontend.
I want to make the normal MS Office file content (.docx, .xlsx, .pptx, .msg etc.) searchable and viewable in the browser.
Files are uploaded to a storage bucket and put in a database with a URL as their handle and a title.
I need to extract the file contents for two purposes:

Make the contents searchable (by storing it in the database).
Making the content viewable in the web front-end.

I prefer to render the contents from the text in the database, as this is more responsive and renders more quickly but it still needs to maintain most, if not all, of the formatting from the source file.
There are a few libraries available on NPM to extract the text contents to make it searchable, but I haven't found anything that consistently extracts contents in such a way that it can easily be transformed to HTML, so it can be rendered in a browser (and I suppose furthermore can handle embedded images in a .docx etc.).
What are the normal approaches to such a problem?

Looks like https://www.npmjs.com/package/mammoth is a good bet for .docx
